# Navigation using href="#!/id"

Tags: jquery, html, navigation

Recently I noticed some websites in which the menu navigation is somewhat like this.

```
    <div id="navigation">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="selected"> HOME </a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/about"> ABOUT </a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/projects"> PROJECTS </a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/contact"> CONTACT </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I also noticed that this **!/** comes inside "single page" sites with animation effects.**[Example](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_41137/#!/pageHome)**(Please look at navigation in source code)
 I tried to use it, but without animation it appears useless. 

My question is,

- `<a href="#about"> ABOUT </a>` navigates to the section within the current page with id='about'. Then what does `<a href="#!/about"> ABOUT </a>` mean?
- Is that someway related to jQuery?Or it is specific to some jQuery plugin?
- If it is, then can I say that, it is not navigating to anywhere, but just a "hide out"(or fake address) for helping animation?(I'm asking like this because without animation, it appears useless).

Comment: Look here for the answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739667/why-does-twitter-use-a-hash-and-exclamation-mark-in-urls-and-how-do-they-rewrit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hashbang has nothing (directly) to do with the animation. It is there to provide a URL that you can link to when you use Ajax to change the content of the page. Google can then translate that URL into one that hits a URL on your site that will give indexable content to Google.

The technique has been obsoleted by [the history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), which allows you to change the URL to a *normal* one on your site instead.

Using a normal URL means that [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) works, and you don't have the performance problems of loading the index page, displaying it to the user, then having JavaScript replace it a few seconds later.

---

If you want to do animation when you load the new content, then you can. It just doesn't have anything to do with the URL changing.