# Why does my url contains "!" when using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I just started with MEAN stack and i'm following some TUTs.

I'm using the `npm-views` from Angular and trying to redirect an html `a` tag to another html file. However when I go to `localhost:3000` I get this: `localhost:3000/#!/` and the when I the link inside that page it simply adds `localhost:3000/#!/#%2Fsl`.

My index.html is this (without some elements -- too much text // I removed all the js and css files but I have them all in my file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="firstApp">

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('firstApp',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
    })
    .when('/sl', {
        templateUrl: 'sl.html',
        controller: 'SLController',
    });

});

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope,  $http){
    console.log('Home page');
});

app.controller('SLController', function ($scope, $http){
    console.log('Signup page');
});

</script>
  <title>First Node.JS app</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <h1 id="indexTitle"> MyFirst App </h1>
    <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My home.html file is this:

```
<div class="container main-forms" id="main-forms">

    <h3 id="letMeIn1"><a href="#/sl" id="letMeIn">Let me in</a></h3>

</div>
```

and my sl.html file is this:

```
    <div class="container main-forms" id="main-forms">

    <div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active tab-btn"><a href="#login" class="tab-link" id="login1" aria-controls="login" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="tab-btn"><a href="#signup" class="tab-link" id="signup1" aria-controls="signup" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="login">

            <div class=" row main col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <form class="form-group">

                    <h3 class="form-titles center-block">Login</h3>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="Usuario">

                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="Password">

                    <input type="submit" class="form-control form-subtitles btn btn-info" value="Login">

                </form>

            </div>


        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="signup">
            <div class=" row main col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <form class="form-group">

                    <h3 class="form-titles center-block">Sign Up</h3>

                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="Usuario">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="E-mail">

                    <input type="password" class="form-control form-subtitles" placeholder="Password">

                    <input type="submit" class="form-control form-subtitles btn btn-info" value="Signup">

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>






      </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/a/4739713/218196 .

Comment: You are using hashbang angular navigation - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the browser is HTML5 browser angularJS will redirect it to #!

Otherwise it will be only #.

Read this documentation here on [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) to find out more on why this happens.

> Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang
>
> URL Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular
>   URL
>
> **HTML5 mode**
>
> In HTML5 mode, the `$location` service getters and setters interact
>   with the browser URL address through the HTML5 history API. This
>   allows for use of regular URL path and search segments, instead of
>   their hashbang equivalents. If the HTML5 History API is not supported
>   by a browser, the $location service will fall back to using the
>   hashbang URLs automatically. This frees you from having to worry about
>   whether the browser displaying your app supports the history API or
>   not; the $location service transparently uses the best available
>   option.
>
> Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang
>   URL Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular
>   URL Note that in this mode, AngularJS intercepts all links (subject to
>   the "Html link rewriting" rules below) and updates the url in a way
>   that never performs a full page reload.
>
> **Example:**

```
it('should show example', function() {
  module(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  });
  inject(function($location) {
    // in browser with HTML5 history support:
    // open http://example.com/#!/a -> rewrite to http://example.com/a
    // (replacing the http://example.com/#!/a history record)
    expect($location.path()).toBe('/a');

    $location.path('/foo');
    expect($location.absUrl()).toBe('http://example.com/foo');

    expect($location.search()).toEqual({});
    $location.search({a: 'b', c: true});
    expect($location.absUrl()).toBe('http://example.com/foo?a=b&c');

    $location.path('/new').search('x=y');
    expect($location.url()).toBe('/new?x=y');
    expect($location.absUrl()).toBe('http://example.com/new?x=y');
  });
});

it('should show example (when browser doesn\'t support HTML5 mode', function() {
  module(function($provide, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $provide.value('$sniffer', {history: false});
  });
  inject(initBrowser({ url: 'http://example.com/new?x=y', basePath: '/' }),
    function($location) {
    // in browser without html5 history support:
    // open http://example.com/new?x=y -> redirect to http://example.com/#!/new?x=y
    // (again replacing the http://example.com/new?x=y history item)
    expect($location.path()).toBe('/new');
    expect($location.search()).toEqual({x: 'y'});

    $location.path('/foo/bar');
    expect($location.path()).toBe('/foo/bar');
    expect($location.url()).toBe('/foo/bar?x=y');
    expect($location.absUrl()).toBe('http://example.com/#!/foo/bar?x=y');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. And what should I do to fix the link that sends me to `localhost:3000/#!/#%2Fsl`

Comment: @DiegoRios Try using `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')`;

Comment: And I don't think i'm running it in a Legacy browser. Is the latest Chrome a legacy browser?