# Weird URL ending with AngularJS routing

Tags: angularjs

I just noticed that for some reason, I get this:

http://localhost/ReportsWeb/#!/

instead of this: http://localhost/ReportsWeb/#/

exclamation sign is added... why, any ideas, cant figure the reason why its where.

Obviously, if I navigate to http://localhost/ReportsWeb, the URL becomes http://localhost/ReportsWeb/#!/

**UPDATE**

Thanks guys for the help.
These two options work fine:
1)
set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`
add `<base href="/ReportsWeb/">`
2)
set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`
set `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`

Which option is "more correct" way to handle this?

To me the second option looks right, I dont need to make any more changes to make my project work. In first case, I need to set base element, but angular routing wont work, I probably have to change all "/#/Path" to exclude the hash tag. So, I'll take option #2 )

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my url contains "!" when using angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033863/why-does-my-url-contains-when-using-angular)

Comment: @Pritam Banerjee, it is similar, but not duplicate, I need to know the difference between these two options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hashbang` mode is a trick that `AngularJS` uses to provide deep-linking capabilities to your Angular apps. In hashbang mode (the fallback for html5 mode), URL paths take a prepended # character. They do not rewrite tags and do not require any server-side support. Hashbang mode is the default mode that AngularJS uses if it’s not told otherwise. A hashbang URL looks like:

```
http://localhost/ReportsWeb/#!/
```

To be explicit and configure hashbang mode, it needs to be configured in the config function on an app module. We can also configure the `hashPrefix`, which, in hashbang mode, is the `!` prefix. This prefix is part of the fallback mechanism that Angular uses for older browsers. We can also configure this character.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
           $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
           $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, should work. You need to set html5Mode to true where you're handling your angular routes, here's some example code of what your app should look like

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {

    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
})
```

Comment: thanks, it works, just needed to add <base href="/ReportsWeb/">

Comment: No problem, html5Mode will remove the remaining # as well if you want that too.

Comment: unfortunately this broke the routing