# What's the significance of "#" or "#!" that appears in website url's

Tags: web-applications, url, fragment-identifier

While browsing some popular websites, I noticed that occasionally the url would change to include these characters "#" or "#!".  Why is this?  From a programmers perspective, what techniques, technologies are they implementing to cause this.  Is this a best practice for a certain solution?

Examples:
http://twitter.com/#!/
http://www.facebook.com/#/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a thorough explanation of hash-urls and hash-bang urls: [HashURIs](http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/154) by Jeni Tennison.

Answer (score 4):

It is a in-document link. It's called anchor (or fragment) and it is used to link to certain parts within a page and have the browser directly scroll to the right part of the page.

Try this (and read the contents :-))
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

This browser mechanism has recently been exploited to perform certain advanced javascript/ajax tricks and it's being used extensively by facebook, twitter, etc. When doing so a general convention is to append a ! after the # to distinguish a javascript-bound anchor from a normal one.