# Change URL from Javascript like facebook does

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, back-button

I'm currently working in a AJAX oriented web application. I have been looking for the different ways of replicating the current AJAX state (or Application state) with the browsers url so refreshing and back-button also works.

In the last weeks I see different approaches involving the use of the hash (#) and different JS-frameworks.

In the documentation it is stated, that changing the browsers URL from JS is not possible. Today I went to Facebook and opened an image, and the url changed (Altough the image was opened in a lightbox). After the image was closed, the browser url changed back to the original page.

Do you have any idea how they achieve this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Github Changing Pages and the URL so smoothly without AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216314/how-is-github-changing-pages-and-the-url-so-smoothly-without-ajax)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but good for supplemental information: [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Comment: @DAvid Thanks for the hint! I think thats a good place to start looking for this! Great help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792859/facebook-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to manipulate the has value at the end of the URL like this:

```
var hashVal = 'somevalue';
window.location.hash = '#' + hashVal;
```

And then the url will become `www.something.com/#somevalue`

Comment: Thanks, but as I explained on the post, I already tried this approach and works fine. 

I'm interesting about doing it without the hash! As facebook does. Should be possible somehow not?

Comment: @Nicolas, facebook uses hashes all  over the place!

Comment: Not really, or at least I don't see them on my url. Can it be that the browser is hidding the hash somehow?

Comment: @Nicolas see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Comment: thanks again for your quick reply. But I have already checked out that link. My version of facebook seems to be using something like this: http://html5demos.com/history/first because I don't see any Hash at all

Comment: I think Nicolas is using an HTML5-enabled browser and Neal is not. Why was this answer accepted?

Answer (score 7):

There is a feature of HTML5 that supports what you are referring to. See http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page.

Some systems implement this by checking for window.history.pushState, and if so, using it, otherwise falling back to hashtags. If SEO is of concern, use #! instead of #. See 
http://code.google.com/intl/es/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the hash value as Neal pointed out. But i would recommend using a library for doing the same. Here's one that i use

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/

Hash values in the URL are manipulated mainly for back button and bookmark integration. Hope this helps.