# Why do some websites have "#!" in the URL

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Why do websites like twitter, 1x.com have a "#!" in their URL?

I was told that the part of the URL string following # isn't sent to the server. How is it possible to load my page then?

Comment: Yes. That is the exact same thing I was looking for.