# ASP.NET Client vs Server View Rendering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, jquery-templates

Using ASP.NET MVC: I am caught in the middle between rendering my views on the server vs in the client (say jquery templates). I do not like the idea of mixing the two as I hear some people say. For example, some have said they will render the initial page (say a list of a bunch of comments) server side, and then when a new comment is added they use client side templating. The requirement to have the same rendering logic in two different areas of your code makes me wonder how people convince themselves it is worth it.

What are the reasons you use to decide which to use where?

How does your argument change when using ASP.NET Web Forms?

Answer (score 3):

One reason that people do that is because they want their sites to get indexed by search engines but also want to have the best user experience, so are writing client code for that. You have to decide what makes sense given the constraints and goals you have. Unfortunately, what makes the most business sense won't always seem to make the most sense from a technical perspective.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage to server-side rendering is that your clients don't have to use javascript in order for your pages to be functional. If you're relying on JQuery templates, you pretty much have to assume that your page won't have any content when rendered without javascript. For some people this is important.

As you say, I would prefer not to use the same rendering logic twice, since you run the risk of letting it get out of sync.

I generally prefer to just leverage partial views to generate most content server-side. Pages with straight HTML tend to render a bit faster than pages that have to be "built" after they've loaded, making the initial load a little speedier.

We've developed an event-based AJAX architecture for our application which allows us to generate a piece of content in response to the result of an action, and essentially send back any number of commands to the client-side code to say "Use the results of this rendered partial view to replace the element with ID 'X'", or "Open a new modal popup dialog with this as the content." This is beneficial because the server-side code can have a lot more control over the results of an AJAX request, without having to write client-side code to handle every contingency for every action.

On the other hand, putting the server in control like this means that the request has to return before the client-side knows what to do. If your view rendering was largely client-based, you could make something "happen" in the UI (like inserting the new comment where it goes) immediately, thereby improving the "perceived speed" of your site. Also, the internet connection is generally the real speed bottleneck of most websites, so just having less data (JSON) to send over the wire can often make things more speedy. So for elements that I want to respond very smoothly to user interaction, I often use client-side rendering.

In the past, search-engine optimization was a big issue here as well, as Jarrett Widman says. But my understanding is that most modern search engines are smart enough to evaluate the initial javascript for pages they visit, and figure out what the page would actually look like after it loads. Google even recommends [the use of the "shebang"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) in your URLs to help them know how to index pages that are dynamically loaded by AJAX.