# Should I use hashbang/shebang?

Tags: ajax, url, hash, hashbang

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for/3952622#3952622) that the idea of the shebang (#!) was so Google

> knows that an alternative conventional
>   URL exists providing the same page
>   "state"

So, if I don't have conventional URLs corresponding to these hash-states, am I right to say that I should be using just a hash and not a shebang?

Background: The hashes are created based on a search form, and the search results are loaded on the same page.  The hashes are there so that people can go back to the URL with the hashes and repeat the same search.

More broadly, is there a reason I *should* have real URLs corresponding to my hashes?

Comment: The last sentence's threefold negation overwhelms me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear, is this a javascript powered site? As far as I'm concerned that would be the only reason that one might need to use a #!. With that said, even the #! can be full of issues, as could be seen for a while during the gawker switch earlier this year.

Comment: Already decided on this but props to you for answering such an old question.  Gave you the upvote/answer