# Using url with /#!/ like twitter does

Tags: ajax, url, jquery, twitter

Does anyone can tell me about what are urls like `blablalba.com**/#!/**dasdas`?

Twitter use them.

I have a problem with requesting page using AJAX, when I hit *Back* button, it doesn't load previous page that loaded using AJAX.

But, I saw in twitter, when you are in *Timeline* tab/page, and click *@Mention* tab, and hit *Back* button, it will bring you to *Timeline* tab/page again not to your previous loaded page (non AJAX). is there a relation between it and url with `/#!/` characters ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Twitter, but your description reads a bit as if you were looking for [Chris Coyer's screencast on using the hash fragment from JavaScript](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/).