# What's this new `#!` in URL convention?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, hashbang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

I noticed that some popular sites started switching to a new URL (convention?), in which a URI segment is no longer prefixed by `/` but rather by `#!/`.

For example, if you type into Twitter `http://twitter.com/stackoverflow`, it will immediately redirect to `http://twitter.com/#!/stackoverflow`.

Had I seen this on Twitter only, I wouldn't have thought twice about this, but now I am seeing this in other sites.

Is this a new convention for URL redirection? Where can I learn more about this?

Comment: I'm 100% positive I've seen this before somewhere...

Comment: Search google for hashbang. The opinions on this are split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was started by Google ( http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ )

> If you're running an AJAX application
>   with content that you'd like to appear
>   in search results, we have a new
>   process that, when implemented, can
>   help Google (and potentially other
>   search engines) crawl and index your
>   content. Historically, AJAX
>   applications have been difficult for
>   search engines to process because AJAX
>   content is produced dynamically by the
>   browser and thus not visible to
>   crawlers. While there are existing
>   methods for dealing with this problem,
>   they involve regular manual
>   maintenance to keep the content
>   up-to-date.

Look at this answer here:

[What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

The opinion on using this is split - Gawker had major issues after taking this up : http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/

Comment: Oh Wow, I searched SO for this before posting but had no idea it's called hashbang. Thanks!

Comment: @uTubeFan hashbang / shebang is very popular in scripting

Comment: @manojlds Yes, I've seen this in sh/ksh/bash scripts but I didn't make the connection to URLs. +1 again. :) Will accept in 8 minutes.

Comment: @manojlds @uTubeFan: It's more often called a shebang in scripting terms (short form of "sharp bang"). I have no idea why "hashbang" caught on among web devs but not "shebang" - probably because web developers weren't shell scripters.

Comment: @manojlds @uTubeFan: Plus it is true that it only popped up in URLs *very* recently - on the other hand it's been indicative to shells for **years**.

Comment: @BoltClock - HaSH Bang is also a reason for shebang

Comment: @BoltClock - you didn't have to mention the second point!

Answer (score 1):

It's how Google should index the page when dealing with AJAX