# How does a website load only part of the page and still display full on URLs?

Tags: ajax

I am looking at the Gawker blogs (http://io9.com, http://lifehacker.com/) and I'm curious about how they are made.

When I click for on a link only the article part of the page reloads displaying a loading icon while it does.

But what I can't figure out is that links point to new URLs like io9.com/something/something and its not something like I see on ajax pages that they put a `site.com/#something` tag at the end of the url from javascript to mark the page after an ajax request.

Can I change the full blown URL from javascript or what is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Answer (score 1):

When it happens, the website is using the HTML5 History API. This API can change the url (via JavaScript) without changing the page.

See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) for browser support.
If you would like to implement it in yout website, [backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org) would be very useful.