# What is the meaning and practicality of having /#/ in a URL?

Tags: url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Does this enable something special? I see it everywhere, like http://www.nikebetterworld.com/#/NYC_Plays_Ball

What is it for? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for This might clear things up.

Comment: Not sure what a URL has to do with HTML5/CSS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mostly used on "ajax" web sites.
When you have page with content displayed by javascript/ajax, one of the problem is the URL is not changing (and you cannot use back button). So developers are using this kind of URL to enhance their websites with *back button compatibility*.

Answer (score 5):

The part after the # is a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), and isn't sent to the server

The browser may also inspect it via javascript (`location.hash`) for example

Answer (score 1):

You probably know that already, but the primary use is jumping to an anchor. In `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Examples` the URL makes the page scroll to the Examples section of that Wikipedia article as soon as it finishes loading.

Lately, it's also been used to allow direct linking/bookmarking and navigation history for Ajax-based sites. See [here](http://mtrpcic.net/2011/02/fragment-uris-theyre-not-as-bad-as-you-think-really/) for details.