# Facebook share with AJAX meta tags

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, facebook, facebook-sharer

This page, when put in Facebook status textbox, grabs the thumbnail, description and page title with my name and thumbnail into the Facebook Sharer textbox:

https://twitter.com/#!/ftwolf

However, it is obviously an AJAX-loaded page (as you can tell by the hash fragment URL).  How can I accomplish the same thing on a page that loads via AJAX?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (Twitter users jquery, too, probably) and its plugin [address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/). It has very simple implemention

```
        $.address.init(function(event) {
            // Initializes plugin support for links
            $('a:not([href^=http])').address();
        }).change(function(event) {
            //do your stuff
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook crawler should work the same way as [google's](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/).

You can test your implementation with the [Facebook linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Comment: It does, and thanks for that link.  I guess I'm doing it right.