# AJAX Url change, hiding #?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, dom-events, hashtag

I want to know if there is a way to hide the hash tag, for the url to look like a static url. I discovered that on facebook, with the theater photo view Chrome and Safari the url looks static like this:
`https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2305829278398&set=p.2305829278398&type=1&theater`

on IE the Url looks like this:
`https://www.facebook.com/#!/photo.php?fbid=2305829278398&set=p.2305829278398&type=1&theater`

is #! just hidden automatically in all browsers except IE (v7) or is facebook reacting different for IE?
or do the other browsers don't need #! for changing the url without refreshing the whole site?

I'm sorry if this question has already been answered, but it is impossible to search for it because search engines ignore symbols like # or !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called `pushState`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

IE10 supposedly will support it. Until then, workarounds are necessary on that browser. The `#!` isn't any sort of formal standard, but it's [common practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for/3009501#3009501) when using the browser hash for navigation.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there would be something like this :)