# What does this string in a url means #!?

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, uri

This is not new to me but I just wandering where it is used or what's it's name?
Google don't return results when I typed this string #!.

Example:

```
http://facebook.com/#!/username
http://beta.theexpressiveweb.com/#!/css3-animations
```

Comment: It's hard to know what to look for. It looks like a "shebang" so: [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a **hashbang URI** and is used in client side javascript-heavy applications to help with the loading of Ajax content.

Here's a pretty good article on it:  http://mtrpcic.net/2011/02/fragment-uris-theyre-not-as-bad-as-you-think-really/

You can also get more info about it from the Wikipedia entry on Fragment Identifiers (check the bottom of this page): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

By the way, the first link describes them well, but be sure the read all of the comments at the bottom.  Like anything, there are pros and cons to using this technique.