# How do you get the anchor/fragment/sharp in a webapp2.RequestHandler?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I can't seem to find the attribute that allows me to get the #something part of www.domain.com/#something. I have tried self.request.url, self.request.path, self.request.uri, etc, these do not include the anchor part of the url. What do I do to get the anchor portion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics.

> Clients are not supposed to send URI-fragments to servers when they
>   retrieve a document

Answer (score 1):

You need to have JavaScript code running in the browser that can access the fragment identifier and make an AJAX call for the actually required data. See Raganwald's answer to this SO question: [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)