# For what is used and what technologies are related to /#!/ in some websites URL's

Tags: hashbang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

I'm curious about for what the expression **/#!/** is used in some websites like Twitter or about.me.

Some examples:
http://twitter.com/#!/search/programmer 
http://about.me/search/#!/tag/programmer

I like to know if there are specific technologies for using that, like a framework or programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#!` is called **hashbang**.

By reading [Gawker Learns the Hard Way Why ‘Hash-Bang’ URLs are Evil](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/) and especially following the links for more technical-oriented information, you'll learn about one side of the story, the problematic one :)

SO: [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) seems to be the most voted question on the subject around here.