# Friendly URL like grooveshark/twitter: example.com/#!/whatever

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

I am trying to get the requested URL from PHP.

The URL is like this: `http://example.com/#!/controller/method/var1`

I want to get the `/controller/method/var1` part from PHP but all I get is `http://example.com/`

How Grooveshark and Twitter handle this?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Comment: As far as I'm aware, anything after the hash is not sent to PHP as it's completely client side.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierBourgeois thank you! i have a lot of info to read about it.

Comment: @Corbin Yes, anything after the hash is not sent to PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter, Grooveshark and Facebook (before) uses Javascript to get this Friendly URL.

Maybe you can use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to get it with php, i am not sure.

Comment: You can't get it with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']  or any other Server variable because is not sent to the server.


But, yes! i will use Javascript to handle the Friendly URl, i will load the header and the footer, and the javascript, then i will get that friendly url to load it with ajax.