# What is the new #_ appended to Wikipedia's URLs? Why?

Tags: url, redirect, wikipedia

Wikipedia's URLs recently started adding `#_` (appended or embedded) to the **mobile** version of the website.

- What does this mean?
- Why did Wikipedia start using this new convention?

I knew about [shebang/hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3009501) (`#!`) but I am not sure I understand the purpose of Wikipedia's new `#_`.

- Is this also related to AJAX?
- How does it work?

BTW, typing the URL into the browser's address without the `#_`, results in auto-redirect to the `#_`-appended URL, which results in significant performance hit on my browser. There must be a good reason to use this new `#_` scheme. I just don't know (yet) what it is.

Comment: Could you describe how exactly does that happen to you? I don't see anything like that.

Comment: @svick Sure. Type http://m.wikipedia.org in your browser (even a desktop one, doesn't have to be mobile).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a dummy value used as a kluge.  The code that sets it was introduced on May 1 in a commit titled ["fix jump to top"](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/extensions/MobileFrontend.git;a=commitdiff;h=4c2098da7ec10995818e2768f7a236bb1b510cd2), with the following commit message:

> "currently clicking on the jump to top link has no effect. This is
>   because opening a section sets the hash to the same as the jump to
>   top link. By resetting it first we can get back the behaviour we want"

If it's really causing a performance issue in your browser, you should probably [report it as a bug in MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Bugzilla).  Actually, you should probably report it as a bug in your browser too.

Comment: Thanks for solving the mystery. Any idea why a [kluge](http://www.learnthat.com/define/view.asp?id=7636) and not a more thoughtful and long term solution?

Comment: Probably because it was broken and needed to be fixed quickly?