# what is use of <a href="#!/home>?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Can anyone suggest me, what is the action taken, mainly:

```
"#!". `<a href="#!/page_Home"><span></span><strong>Home Page</strong></a>`
```

Comment: It's a [terrible hack](http://www.google.ca/search?q=google+hashbang+url&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to let Google index your AJAX content.

Comment: @meagar - You should post that comment as an answer.

Comment: More likely this should be closed as a duplicate, if I weren't so lazy.

Answer (score 0):

browser will try to bring element with id `!/page_Home` in window view.  but developers usually use this  to take some action in JavaScript using `onhashchange` event(eg . navigate).
 I use `hashchange` to open new app in my web site.

[more information](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs)

Comment: No, this is not what hashbang is for.

Comment: After the update it is better. I remove my downvote, but still cannot upvote it for not having enough information.