# Use of hashbang (#!) in urls

Tags: url, hashbang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

What are hashbang and what are the uses of hashbang in hyperlinks?