# Why using #! instead of # in Ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

I see in several web-based application that uses Ajax request for loading pages, they use `#!` after urls instead of `#`. For instance: `/boo.php#!Projects` instead of `/boo.php#Projects`.

I want to know, is there any technical reason for doing like that or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3009380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent is to make AJAX pages crawlable by e.g. Google.

Normally, everything behind a hash in a URL is irrelevant for a crawler and is not send to the server at all. In AJAX applications it used to be heavily used for "simulating" a real URL in the browsers address bar (people now typically use `history.pushState`).

To come around the limitation of not being ale to execute the full JavaScript application, Google invented a protocol that basically states that if it encounters a URL containing a hashbang like

```
http://example.com/foo#!key=value
```

it can transform it to

```
http://example.com/foo?_escaped_fragment_=key=value
```

And send it to the server. The server then is expected to return a representation of the page as it would have been shown in the JavaScript app. In the end it is just a convention to make these apps crawlable.

For more information, see the [documentation on the topic](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) by Google.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the hashbang/shebang (`#!`) is Googles scheme for indexing AJAX pages:

> When your site adopts the scheme, it will be considered "AJAX
>   crawlable." This means that the crawler will see the content of your
>   app if your site supplies HTML snapshots.

More info on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "hashbang". It's used by Google to index Ajax-based website. More info there - http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2011/02/09/using-hash-bangs-in-your-urls/