# Backbone and SEO cloaking

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, seo

So I am building a page using Backbone.js that contains a jquery datatable and a panel with search options (to filter data in the datatable). Now that I would like this page to be indexed by Google or other engines.

The question is that, the search panel is created and appended using backbone views via Javascript, which means Google would not see that as the crawler does not execute javascript.

IS THIS considered to be an SEO cloaking? Will the website get banned?

Comment: Google crawler supports JS these days

Comment: well, not entirely I say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not SEO cloaking.  It is very common to load data in this manner and search engines nor adword programs ban websites doing this.

(SEO cloaking is when you are trying to trick search engines in to thinking your site has data that it really does not.)

Comment: Hey John, when i searched on Internet, some refer javascript cloaking as : "users with JavaScript enabled browsers are shown one version while users with JavaScript turned off (like search engines) are shown another version of a website." 

Since the search panel could not be loaded by crawler, isnt this kind of "showing another version of a website"?

Comment: From wikipedia: Cloaking is a search engine optimization (SEO) technique in which the content presented to the search engine spider is different from that presented to the user's browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be considered as cloaking, will it lead to your site going down in google's results is another question...

You have 3 options if you absolutely want to avoid it :

- use hashbang (#!) : [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)
- generate the exact same initial html server side and enhance it with js once loaded in the browser without changing the first content shown
- use phantomjs to generate your real rich pages server side when you detect that it is google bot that wants them.

All 3 are quite expensive in terms of dev/architecture, but google does not provide "real" support for applications today.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is considered cloaking. Google advocates using a headless browser to render pages that rely heavily on JS (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.au/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html).