# Why is Wordpress inserting "#!" into URLs?

Tags: javascript, wordpress-theming, hashbang

```
if ( window.location.href.search('#!/') == -1 && window.location.href !== et_site_url && window.location.href !== ( et_site_url + '#' ) ) {
            access_without_ajax = true;
            $et_main_content.css( { opacity : 1, top : '77px', width : '800px', height : ( et_window_height - 200 ), marginTop : 0, marginLeft : '-400px' } );
            $logo_area.hide();
            $main_menu.hide();
            $et_footer_menu.css({'display':'block','opacity':1, bottom: '0'})
            $('#content').appendTo( $et_page_content );
            $et_main_content.jScrollPane( { animateScroll: true } );
            et_center_content_area();
            et_init_scripts();
        } else if ( window.location.href === et_site_url || window.location.href === ( et_site_url + '#' ) ) {
            $et_main_content.css( { 'margin-left' : '-' + ( content_width / 2 ) + 'px', top: ( ( et_window_height - $et_main_content.height() ) / 2 - 100 ) } ).animate( { opacity : 1, 'top' : ( ( et_window_height - $et_main_content.height() ) / 2 ) }, fade_in_speed, 'easeInOutQuad' );
```

This is adding /#!/ right in the middle of my URL when creating pages in Wordpress. How do I get rid of this garbage?

Comment: It is probably not garbage. Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for

Comment: Thing is, in Chrome when I click the link the page does not come up. It barely works in FF either. I'm not a js pro so wasn't sure if I could just remove some code so it doesn't insert this.

Comment: It would be hard to comment. Not sure if that would mess other functionality up .

Comment: It's not garbage. @karthikr's first comment explains it. +1

Comment: This snippet is definitely not adding `/#!/` to your URLs, that must be happening elsewhere. This code just looks whether the hashbang is already apparent, and only if it is not it will act somehow.