# Changing a jQuery loading bar so it doesn't redirect (Similar to Youtube new loading bar)

Tags: jquery, css

I have this loading bar that is a Jquery Plugin that is available here:
http://www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Smooth-Progress-Bar-Loading-Effect-With-jQuery.html

However, the bar works on a redirect instead of displaying what actually loads. When the below code from $(this).children().html ... is in place, I see the progress bar in my Inspect Element tab go from 0% - 100%. Which is great as it loads, But I want the page to stay current and to load what ever other page is clicked, once the bar is at 100% instead.

Kind of similar to the new youtube red pre-loader. Pretty sure this script is capable of this but after hours of tweaking and attempting changes, I can't seem to work out how.

I'm a PHP head and new jQuery :/

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function loading(percent){
        $('.progress span').animate({width:percent},1000,function(){
            $(this).children().html(percent);
            if(percent=='100%'){
                $(this).children().html('Loading Complete, Redirect to Home Page...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.container').fadeOut();
                    location.href="http://www.jqueryscript.net";
                },1000);
            }
        })
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a silly way of doing an Ajax redirect. You don't want to load the new page completely, *that's why* Ajax should be really beneficial, because you only need to refresh the inner content.

A better way of loading a page via Ajax would include:

- Make calls to the same URL when using Ajax **and** normal loads. Use your server side to pick up on the HTTP Header `X-REQUESTED-WITH: XMLHTTPRequest`, and if it's present, just send across the content. That way users without JavaScript can click on the same links and visit the standalone versions
- For newer browsers, you want to update the browser's URL without actually changing the page. This is best achieved using `window.history.pushState` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338642/updating-address-bar-with-new-url-without-hash-or-reloading-the-page), but bear in mind that support for is very limited, particularly if your target audience are using IE.

  - I've never actually used it myself, but I know [Ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) is quite a popular plugin which will help you get around this issue. As I'm aware it'll use the `pushState` if available, else it'll use "hashbangs" to update the URL. These were very popular with large sites such as [Twitter and Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for), but if you're using a modern browser you may notice they don't use them any more. They tended to divide opinion, mostly because they don't keep a proper track of a user's history, but as far as I'm aware they're the only option for older browsers. I suggest you read up more on them.
- Maybe there are better options out there, but [this tutorial](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/) shows you one way of getting the progress for each request.
- Finally, when constructing your load bar, I'd not bother with using jQuery to make a nice slide effect, but use CSS to `transition` based on `width`. Your jQuery then only has to change the `width` of the load-bar element, and the CSS will take care of the rest. [See tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/)

Comment: I'll have a read and look up. I am after a quick solution for the mean time as the site is going through an update anyway.

Comment: Don't bother with a quick solution for loading your pages, or it'll be crap. That said, the Ajaxify plugin is very easy to get to grips with.

Comment: what would be your best plugin/method of replicating the youtube load bar?

Comment: What do you mean? Just the actual visual load bar itself? Take the steps I said above and then instead of making a standard progress bar make one that is stuck to the top of the screen and has a red glow? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: as in it will take me quite a while, using AJAX requests and using jQuery will take quite a while to figure how to do it and how to do it properly...

Comment: I don't see how that clears up your last question? If you want to "display what actually loads" then you do that using Ajax. I think the best solution is to use Ajax loading for all browsers that understand `pushState`. For all others just fallback to standard page loads. I'd assume this is what YouTube do.