# Is it possible to change the url of the given page?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have ASP.NET application and use the same ASPX page to display 3 different steps in some process. The address looks as following:

```
http://site/Order.aspx?ActionID=a&ActionDate=b&SeatType=&SeatsID=c&RowNumber=&Price=d&OpenID=e&MuzTVPas=e
```

But, on last step I need to display different url address that should look as following:

```
http://site/Order.aspx?Basket=thanks
```

So, is it possible to force displaying another address without all those parameters?

Comment: Do you use Response.Redirect() for going to next step?

Comment: No. We use post back on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only way this can be done is to use the [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) on the client, can't imagine it's possible to do this server-side without causing a postback.

Comment: @tesicg [HTML5: Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Comment: But, as I know not all versions of IE support it. Is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: @tesicg the only alternative I can think of is the hashbang URL but you *probably* don't want to do that. I suggest you read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for), I'd recommend for older browsers you simply for a refresh of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL Rewrite Module to acchieve this.
[Click here for more information.](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)