# What's the difference between hashbang and pushstate?

Tags: javascript

I did not understand how **hashbang** and **pushstate** differ in JavaScript...

pushState()

Answer (score 2):

They are two different things.

1. [Hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) is a programming pattern used to load content using Ajax in such a way that machines (like google bots) can index this content.
2. [Pushstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) is a javaScript API function meant to store a specific state of the current  page in the window.history object so that you can go back to that state using the back button.