# Rewriting an URL with a hashtag

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

simple question, I don't find a working answer.

I have multiple sites like this:

```
www.example.com/#ajax/shipping.php
www.example.com/#ajax/pricing.php
www.example.com/#ajax/inventory.php
```

And want to only show www.example.com. I just can't find how I put this in .htaccess the best way. Can somebody assist please?

This is what I have in .htaccess right now:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `#` denotes the fragment identifier; it doesn't get sent to the server.

Comment: so I can't remove it?

Comment: You can remove/alter it but only on the client side

Comment: Ok, so what should I use instead?

Comment: If you remove `#` and make it `www.example.com/` instead of `www.example.com/#ajax/shipping.php` how will you page be correctly loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The URL fragment (everything from # on) not even gets sent to the server.

Maybe you want to consider a JavaScript based solution, where the actual content will be loaded via AJAX dependent on the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, everything after # doesn't even get to the server. 
Maybe this will intrest you [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)