# What does this link syntax "/#/ - mean in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I see this syntax of links in AngularJS applications:

```
<a href="/#/something">something</a>
```

Why is there the '/#/' in the link, and what does it achieve? I think I might have also seen a version with a bang in it, something like

```
<a href="/!#/login">
```

or

```
<a href="/#!/login">
```

What is the purpose of the `!`?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the '#' or the '!' in a link used with angular (and many other JavaScript libraries) is for client-side routing.

Take a look at the $location service documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The hashtag is in the link for non-HTML5 browsers to prevent the browser from making the actual href call. It's actually not needed for most browsers these days.