# GET query style arguments from hash bang URL

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, hash

I have This Url Using hash bang method:

```
mydomain/gallery/view/246/gallery-title/#!/page=2&order=desc
```

for rewrite url :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(gallery)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&type=$2&id=$3&title=$4&lang=en [NC,L,QSA]
```

No I need to `GET` page number(`i.e:2`) and order(`desc`) value from url. how to get this value?

Comment: The `hash bang` is processed client side.

Comment: @chris85: Sure but i think can get using client side method (`javascript`) Or `Php` `Parse_url`

Comment: You can't use any PHP function on it, it never gets to the server. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3951093/4333555

Answer (score -2):

This can not work because the hashbang is never sent to the server, you can confirm this by checking your logs.

As a workaround for example can change the hashbang to normal query parameters using [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) so they are available on the server.