# I am using angular, and my url always has a "!" (exclamation mark)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For example:

```
http://localhost/#!/login.html
```

I don't need "!". How would I remove it?

```
eg:http://localhost/#/login.html
```

This is my router code :

```
  // Redirect any unmatched url
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login.html");
$stateProvider.state('login', {
    url: "/login.html",
    templateUrl: "views/login.html",
    data: {pageTitle: "login", isLeft: false},
    controller: "LoginCtrl",
    resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                name: 'myApp',
                files: [
                    'controllers/LoginCtrl.js'
                ]
            });
        }]
    }
});
```

I think  Angular-ui-router might have a problem,  but I can't find the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your routing code?

Comment: [Google's crawlable AJAX proposal](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) (obsolete as of HTML5). Angular defaults to this: [hashBang mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-). `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to make HTML5 mode default (you'll still get the hashbang in older browsers, and it's a good thing).

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hashbang Mode**

Hashbang mode is a trick that AngularJS uses to provide deep-linking capabilities to your Angular
apps. In hashbang mode (the fallback for html5 mode), URL paths take a prepended # character.
They do not rewrite  tags and do not require any server-side support. Hashbang
mode is the default mode that AngularJS uses if it’s not told otherwise.
A hashbang URL looks like:

> http://yoursite.com/#!/inbox/all

To be explicit and configure hashbang mode, it needs to be configured in the config function on an
app module

> We can also configure the hashPrefix, which, in hashbang mode, is the
>   ! prefix. This prefix is part of the fallback mechanism that Angular
>   uses for older browsers. We can also configure this character.

**To configure the hashPrefix:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've got it!

Comment: @Jigar7521 Is it better to have the '!' or is it better to not have it at all?

Comment: actually '!' is a kind of mark which helps to identified routes and controller which is called, so it is better to have it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$locationProvider.hasPrefix = '!';
```

I think you are configured $locationProvider like this.Remove this to avoid the `!`

Comment: $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!')

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('page');
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                controller: "homecontroller"

            });
```