# Change the URL format in angular js from # to #!

Tags: angularjs, url, url-routing

Change the below url

http://example.com/#/alphabits/a b c

to

http://example.com/#!/alphabits/a_b_c

Any suggestion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478676/i-am-using-angular-and-my-url-always-has-a-exclamation-mark/40478862

Answer (score 2):

You can change this from [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider). I used this code in my application to change this.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); // We are actually removing ! from URLs as ! is default one.
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.tpl.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/about.tpl.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

  }]);
```