# What does #! mean in ui.router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the Angular ui.router to navigate through my application.
Usually, the url should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8001/#/start
```

But in my case, it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8001/#!/start
```

What does it mean?

I also recognized that if I am calling an URL from this site which is different from my start page, I always get redirected as the URL seems to be invalid.

```
mainApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
'use strict';
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('start');
$stateProvider
    .state('start', {
        url: '/start',
        templateUrl: 'views/start.html'
    })
    .state('registration-activate', {
        url: '/registration/activate/{activationKey}',
        templateUrl: 'views/registration-activation.html'
    })
    ;
    }]);
```

Whenever I try to call localhost:8001/#/registration/activate/xyz I get redirected to the start page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478676/i-am-using-angular-and-my-url-always-has-a-exclamation-mark/40478862

Comment: I checked my configuration, but I didn't set the hashPrefix. Is it a matter that I use gulp to simulate a webserver?

Answer (score 3):

Okay guys, thanks for your explanations.
I resolved my problem that I can't call a URL from a link simply by adding this to my configuration:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the browser is HTML5 browser angularJS will redirect it to `#!`

Otherwise it will be only `#`.

Read this [documentation here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) on `$location` to find out more on why this happens.

> - Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang URL
> - Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular URL

Comment: Okay, but why can't I open a URL? I am always redirected to the start page.