# Vue Router 2 use hashbang instead of hash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, prerender

I am about to use prerender.io on my website which is a SPA built on Vue and Laravel. By default vue-router seems to use hash (domain.com/#/page) instead of hashbang (domain.com/#!/page) which seems to be what prerender is requiring.

I have googled a ton on "Change hash to hashbang vue-router 2" and stuff, but I can not find any help. Does anyone here know where I can tweak vue-router to use hashbang?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See mode here. Unless `abstract` is hashbang, it doesn't appear to be supported. Also, I understood that hashbang was deprecated. https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/options.html http://stackoverflow.com/a/3009501/38065

Comment: We recommend removing the # from the URL entirely and using html5 push state if possible. Google will still crawl using the `_escaped_fragment_` crawling protocol, which Prerender.io supports by default.