# htaccess search and replace redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, webserver

I need to redirect all traffic with an URL including "#" character and replace the character by XYZ.

For example, a request to

> http://www.example.com/page.php?var=test#1

needs to be redirected to

> http://www.example.com/page.php?var=test#XYZ

the # can be anywhere in the URL query

Is it possible to do it with an htaccess ? AFAIK it won't work with PHP because anything next to # is ignored by the script (unless you have something to suggest me)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do it with an htaccess

No. The `#` and everything after it is a [URL fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). It's never sent to the server, thus there's no way the webserver, or mod_rewrite (or, like you said, a script like php) even knows it's there.

You're going to have to do something that's strictly on the client's end in order to change a fragment (e.g. using javascript). The htaccess file can't help you at all.

For example, see the answer to this question: [Remove fragment in URL with JavaScript w/out causing page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269044/remove-fragment-in-url-with-javascript-w-out-causing-page-reload)

Comment: I tried the script in this link, it will remove the anchor and everything next to it. But i just want to replace # by XYZ and keep everything after the character