# How do you remove anchor tags from URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove the anchor tags used when toggling the accordions or a link that includes an anchor to another part of the page.

```
http://rivo.wpengine.com/why-rivo/#toggle-id-3
```

I would like to removing the `#toggle-id-3` part of this URL.

Can I do something with the `.htaccess` file, maybe using mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use htaccess or mod_rewrite to remove URL fragments because they are *never sent to the server*. As far as the server is concerned, they don't exist. You'll need to use javascript or some other client side solution to remove them.

For example, from: [Remove fragment in URL with JavaScript w/out causing page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269044/remove-fragment-in-url-with-javascript-w-out-causing-page-reload)

```
// remove fragment as much as it can go without adding an entry in browser history:
window.location.replace("#");

// slice off the remaining '#' in HTML5:    
if (typeof window.history.replaceState == 'function') {
  history.replaceState({}, '', window.location.href.slice(0, -1));
}
```