# Remove anchor from URL and history

Tags: javascript, url, anchor

I have just added a back-to-top button to my blog with a simple `<a href='#top'...`

I face an annoying behavior that I don't see in other website's back-to-top button:

1. The `#top` suffix is added to the URL - I get this one but I want to change it so it won't affect the original URL.
2. Once I hit that button and sent back to the top of the page, a following press on the back button (alt+left) takes me to the point in the same page where I hit the back-to-top button - This is one I don't get at all. How can I prevent from this entry to get in the history?

I tried to put the code suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20198758/1692261 - in my `head` tag but it has 0 effect.

Edit: I add another requirement here - I want to disable the above behavior just for that button. In the future I might use anchors here and there and I would like the original behavior to take place. Is that possible or it must be block-all or allow-all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Window.scroll() method should work for you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

the window.scroll() method does not have any effect to the url. it just tells the window, to scroll to a specific coordinate ( top: y, left: x )

instead of using the anchor tag, add an eventListener to the button, that fires the Window.scroll()

```
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.scroll({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

you could calculate the exact position of your window.scroll()-target relative to the body element with this:

```
const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
      elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
      offset   = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top;
```

and than use the calculated offset for the top value in the window.scroll()

```
window.scroll({
  top: offset,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```