# Redirect an address ending with #!

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have an address: `www.domain.com/index.php?category=this-is-me#!`

For some reason google directs to this address.
I want to redirect my users to `www.domain.com/index.php?category=this-is-me`

How can I do that?
I don't think the "#!" is needed.

I work with htaccess files (php, apache).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything about it in htaccess files, in php, or in apache. Everything starting from the `#` is called the URI fragment and it is *never sent to the server*. So apache doesn't even know it's there.

What you'll need to do is use something that's on the client-side (e.g. browser) to remove it. For javascript, see something like this: [Remove fragment in URL with JavaScript w/out causing page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269044/remove-fragment-in-url-with-javascript-w-out-causing-page-reload)