# Apache Rewrite rule for named anchors

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, polymer, hashtag

I have a Polymer site for which I need to write a rewrite rule.

Currently there is `example.com/index.html#contact`, `example.com/index.html#FAQ` and so on. It works by default in the browser as `example.com/#contact`, `example.com/#FAQ`, ...

I want it to be accessible as `example.com/contact`, `example.com/FAQ`, ...

I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html#$1 [NE]
```

However, when I add the `R` flag to the last line it "works". Unfortunately, with the `R` flag the address becomes visible in the browser as `example.com/index.html#home` and I don't want that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use htaccess or mod_rewrite to remove URL fragments because they are *never sent to the server*. As far as the server is concerned, they don't exist. You'll need to use javascript or some other client side solution to remove them.

[Remove fragment in URL with JavaScript w/out causing page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269044/remove-fragment-in-url-with-javascript-w-out-causing-page-reload)

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting. In fact, I might need that later on. For now, I'm just trying to internally redirect the /foo to index.html#foo on the server.