# How to solve/fix DOM XSS issue reported by OWASP ZAP?

Tags: asp.net, xss, owasp, zap

I am using OWASP ZAP to scan my web-application, developed using asp.net framework/C#.
I am being tasked by company to ensure NO error reported by OWASP ZAP.

The OWASP ZAP reported this log:
Issue: Cross Site Scripting (DOM Based)
URL:

```
http://[WEBSITE]/myapplication/script.aspx#jaVasCript:/*-/*`/*\`/*'/*"/**/(/* */oNcliCk=alert() )//%0D%0A%0d%0a//</stYle/</titLe/</teXtarEa/</scRipt/--!>\x3csVg/<sVg/oNloAd=alert()//>\x3e
```

I understand that the fragment (#hex) will not be sent to server for processing, it is more for browser to process.

So what do i suppose to do to ensure it never gets reported again in OWASP ZAP?
I've done following actions, but with no luck:

1. On the page, I embedded the javascript code, to remove the hashtag in the url. ([Remove fragment in URL with JavaScript w/out causing page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269044/remove-fragment-in-url-with-javascript-w-out-causing-page-reload)). It works, and I can see it being removed on the browser. But OWASP ZAP still reporting it as problem.
2. Similar to #1, i come out with javascript to detect whether #-fragment-url exists in URL. If exists, then redirect to "error" page. It is working, but ZAP again still report it as problem.

I guess since browser never send the # to the server for validation, i have no way to sanitize it. By the time ZAP/browser receives the response, ZAP will report it as issue.

So, what shall i do? I just want OWASP ZAP never report this issue anymore.
Any ideas?

Comment: Stop depending on document.location or window.location to build page content?

Comment: Check: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Comment: @kingthorin, i went to the document link you provided. I never use any of those DOM-manipulation, such as window.location etc. In fact, i can come out with a simple page with no script, but still OWASP ZAP will complain about this. It sounds to me, it is a false alarm, but i don't think my IT security guy will buy my argument.

Comment: The ZAP DOM XSS rule is usually pretty solid - it uses a real browser and only raises an issue if the browser triggers an alert popup. So my initial assumption would be that this is a valid attack. Try to reproduce the issue in a browser. If you are sure that its a false positive then see if you can create a standalone page based on yours which ZAP still complains about and submit it to us as an issue: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues We'll aim to either show it is a real vulnerability or fix ZAP so that it wont report it

Comment: @davidtj Could you resolve your problem?